# Move deleted files from dropbox account (like a Windows Recycle Bin)

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox offers a history of deleted files, with the option of undeleting them *in place* (see below)[image: screenshot] .

Is it possible to make a backup of *all deleted files* into a single location, like you would copy all files from a windows recycle bin? Doing so manually is not an option given the huge number of files. An external script might be a good solution.

Preserving the folder hierarchy would be a plus, but mixing undeleted files with the existing ones would be worse than all.

**Context note:** I'm doing data recovery after a disk crash (using boxifier), and the clock is ticking because dropbox "trash" expires after one month. I want to keep those files as security

Comment: Recovery is a browser only feature what's possibles is offered on the DropBox website

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't understand you answer. I have access to both the desktop app and the web app; and the app will be probably more useful for this case

Comment: Desktop app doesn't have a way to restore deleted files. Only way to restore files is via Dropbox web interface. I hope that make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

> make a backup of all deleted files into a single location

Yes, but it would have to be a manual effort on your part using Dropbox's web interface.

As you can see, Dropbox is not a recovery tool when your disk goes bad. Best you can expect is a point in time restore from when Dropbox last performed a full sync. If you want Extended History, you can always buy the feature temporarily.

You should consider using a second tool for backup & recovery. Even Windows Backup is adequate for this purpose and is quite good at doing point in time restore of specific files and folders.